# Correlation and Max and Min of Two Exponentials

Tags: random-variable, exponential-distribution

Came across an interesting problem:

> Let X and Y be independent random variables such that both X and Y ∼ Exp(1).
>
> Define L = min(X,Y) and H = max(X,Y).
>
> What is ρ(L, H)? Why must the correlation should be positive?

I'm confused by how to figure this out. So far, I've defined D to be a random variable tracking the amount of time that passes between the first and second events, so that D = H - L.

Comment: This doesn't read as a stand-alone question. What are L and H?

Comment: @dipetkov Right, fixed!

Comment: Please don't repost your question: just edit the original.